# jQuery button click with Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is how the manifest.json file looks like.

```
{
"name": "Countdown",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Countdown Extension"
},
"background" : {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "LeoScript.js"]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
}
```

The background.js file

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
  alert(response);
});
```

and this is the LeoScript.js file

```
$(function(){
  $(".simple-image-button DOQN2G-c-A").click(function ()
  {
    alert("Hello World!");
  });
 });
```

The jquery is working fine but for some reason whenever that button is clicked, nothing happens. I have tried using $document ready function as well but that also fails to work. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong because of which the alert if not firing.

Comment: The first and foremost thing to do in such cases is to [debug](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) the content script and see whether the element `.simple-image-button DOQN2G-c-A` exist when the content script is executed.

Comment: How can I check that if the element exists or not?

Comment: I do not think that the element exists when the script is executed. What can I do about it

Comment: `[prevObject:m.fn.init[1], context: document, selected: ".simple-image-button DOQN2G-c-A"]` This is what comes in the console. This means that the element is there, right?

Comment: `<button type="button" class="simple-image-button DOQN2G-c-A" title="Refresh"></button>` if this is the button then what should I be using in the jquery?

Comment: `.simple-image-button.DOQN2G-c-A` - note the dot between the classes.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much